# How to Provide Username & Password when Starting Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I want to set username and password protection to Drill. Because if anyone know my storage plugin name, they will automatically access Drill. So, I want restriction to my Drill.

**Is there any way to provide password while starting drill ?**

Note: *I am starting drill in embedded mode.*

Comment: Check configuring user authentication in Drill : https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-authentication/

Comment: Did you try with these docs?

Comment: ya i am trying.. but didn't succeed. The Problem i am facing is.. i have enabled the impersonation and security in drill-overide-confi file, But after that how & where i will give user name and password... i am confuse.?? Pls help me.

Comment: @dev: Help me regarding username and password..

Comment: In which folder or file, we have to give username and pass..??

Comment: Naveen I got some issue while trying authentication. I did not spend much time. Kind of busy with my projects. Drill uses PAM authentication. So firstly, you need to have idea about PAM authentication. Study a little bit about that. Then try as per docs.

Comment: ok.. Thanks  for ur help...

Comment: @Dev:    !connect jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181
 

      Enter username for jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181: bob
      Enter password for jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181: *************
   
   
   My Question is: Where to give this username- bob & Password:- ****  ??? I which file and folder??

Comment: how to use PAM authentication in window for apache drill

Comment: I have not worked on authenticating drill

Comment: @dev: whether you know .. PAM  Authentication will work for Apache Drill  in Window Platform or not.??